# Word for someone who remains calm (and taunts) in arguments

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes someone who remains calm in arguments, even when the other side is extremely angry? For example, someone who *smiles and replies to angry remarks*? I thought of *taunting*, but it doesn't suit the situation I'm thinking of.

Example sentence: He was            even when the English teacher yelled at him, making the teacher extremely angry.

Note: It shouldn't mean calm, but more like taunting or sneering, in a calm way.

Comment: When they remain calm and taunt do they do this because underneath they are seething but they do not want to show it or because they are so far above the argumsnt that they are merely amused and they are playing with their adversary?

Answer (score 1):

It's sort of depends on the context.

For example, my father was famous for his **stoicism** when my mother argued with him, which of course made her angrier and ultimately violent.

But over time the blood would drain from my father's face and his **expression hardened in defiance,** but we all knew he was about to lose his $hit."

But my sister would remain **calm** in an argument, with a **sarcastic expression**, is if she thought I was foolish."

Comment: We try to set mentions in italic here when possible.

Comment: @tchrist sorry I'm new here. smile... What do you mean by mentions? in the above example are you saying to replace the bold with italic?

Comment: Welcome to our site. I didn't edit your post because I wasn't sure which sentences you wanted to be example sentences you were quoting or citing or creating on the fly for illustrative purposes, and which were just talking about the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

***[self-controlled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-controlled)***
(adjective   usually approving)

> having strong control over your emotions and actions.

*”He was self controlled  even when the English teacher yelled at him.*”

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I think *composed* can be used in this context, as it is a synonym for the word *calm* itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Equanimous* among countless other synonyms of the word would fit the bill.

> If you're equanimous, you're serene and calm. People who are equanimous seem enviably composed and balanced.

[Vocabulary.com]